# Is there a WW2 European bomb damage atlas?

Tags: world-war-two, book, ww2-european-theater, reference, bombing

For London there is a comprehensive and accessible (and [readily available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0500518254)) [atlas of damage](https://www.theguardian.com/cities/gallery/2015/sep/02/hand-coloured-bomb-damage-maps-london-in-pictures) done during the Second World War by German aerial bombing.

[image]

Are there similar atlases available for Europe, especially for Germany or key cities in Germany? I know both the US (through the Strategic Bombing Survey) and Britain (through the British Bombing Survey Unit) conducted surveys of bomb damage after the war, but can't find a presentation of these that is accessible in the same way the London survey is.

Is there a WW2 European bomb damage atlas (or atlases) available, similar to the *The London County Council Bomb Damage Maps*?

Comment: For Berlin, I have found https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/?loginkey=showMap&mapId=gebschaden_1945@senstadt and http://www.deutschefotothek.de/documents/obj/90015127/df_dk_0010001_3546_1985 . You can assume that on maps of damage in Berlin that were created after the war, some of the damage is from surface combat rather than aerial.bombardment.

Comment: I am pretty sure similar maps were created for other cities, but I could not find any others on the web.

Comment: For Berlin, select [Gebäudeschäden 1945](https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/index.jsp?Szenario=light) to view the 1945 damaged buildings maps, that were assembled between 1945 and 1950.

Answer (score 1):

Found *[dlozeve.github.io](https://dlozeve.github.io/ww2-bombings/)* while cruising around looking for something else entirely.  Have you seen it?

Comment: Interesting, but I think it *is* something else entirely.